# xpath 1.0 first and last nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

How do i select only the first and the last nodes using an xpath 1.0 statement?

`Vehicle/Car[position() = 1]` works correctly

`Vehicle/Car[position() = last]` works correctly

however when i try and put them together it only brings back the first result and ignores the second condition.
I've tired what i think should work:

```
Vehicle/Car[position() = 1 or position() = last()]
```

but this only brings back the first position.

I've also tried alternatives such as:

```
Vehicle/Car[position() = 1][position() = last()]
```

which all seem to return only the first not the first and the last.

**added*** example input and output as requested.

**input example:**

```
<Vehicle>
    <Car>
        <CarNumber>123</CarNumber>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <CarNumber>456</CarNumber>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <CarNumber>789</CarNumber>
    </Car>
</Vehicle>
```

**expected output:**

```
123789
```

**actual output:**

```
123
```

**xslt:**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="Vehicle/Car[position() = 1 or position() = last()]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your first code works fine

Comment: i make xml `<Vehicle>
   <Car>Opel</Car>
   <Car>Mazda</Car>
   <Car>Chevrolet</Car>
</Vehicle>` xpath returns `Element='<Car>Opel</Car>'
Element='<Car>Chevrolet</Car>'`

Comment: Please include sample `XML` with your `xpath` question.

Comment: If you are using XSLT-1.0, and this xpath is in `xsl:value-of` it would give you only the first value. Try using XSLT-2.0 and expect both the values.

Comment: @LingamurthyCS I can only use 1.0, is the above not possible in one statement on 1.0?

Comment: @gardni Please show us the input, expected output, and the complete code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="Vehicle/Car[position() = 1 or position() = last()]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

try:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Vehicle/Car[position() = 1 or position() = last()]">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

As was already explained, in XSLT 1.0 `xsl:value-of` returns only the value of the first node in the selected node-set.

Answer (score 2):

This expression

```
Vehicle/Car[position() = 1 or position() = last()]
```

is correct. I suspect the problem is in how you are using the result. Perhaps you are using a construct like `xsl:value-of` which (in XSLT 1.0) discards all elements except the first.

Comment: this looks like the problem i'm having because im testing my xpath in xslt. The xpath syntax is correct, but it's the xslt that has a problem?